# Comparison shell script for large text/csv files - improvement needed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, comparison, large-data

My task is the following - I have two CSV files:

File 1 (~9.000.000 records):
**type(text),number,status(text),serial(number),data1,data2,data3**

File 2 (~6000 records):
**serial_range_start(number),serial_range_end(number),info1(text),info2(text)**

The goal is to add to each entry in File 1 the corresponding info1 and info2 from File 2:
**type(text),number,status(text),serial(number),data1,data2,data3,info1(text),info2(text)**

I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="file1.csv"
RANGE="file2.csv"

for SN in `cat $USER | awk  -F , '{print $4}'`
    do
#echo \n "$SN"
    for LINE in `cat $RANGE` 
            do
    i=`grep $LINE $RANGE| awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    #echo \n "i= " "$i"
    j=`grep $LINE $RANGE| awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    #echo \n "j= " "$j"
    k=`echo $SN`
    #echo \n "k= " "$k"
    if [ $k -ge $i -a $k -le $j ] 
        then
        echo `grep $SN $USER`,`grep $i $RANGE| cut -d',' -f3-4` >> result.csv
        break
        #else
        #echo `grep $SN $USER`,`echo 'N/A','N/A'` >> result.csv
    fi
    done
done
```

The script works rather good on small files but I'm sure there is a way to optimize it because I am running it on an i5 laptop with 4GB of RAM.
I am a newbie in shell scripting and I came up with this script after hours and hours of research, trial and error but now I am out of ideas.

note: not all the info in file 1 can be found in file.

Thank you!
Adrian.

**FILE EXAMPLES and additional info:**

File 1 example:

```
prep,28620026059,Active,123452010988759,No,No,No
post,28619823474,Active,123453458466109,Yes,No,No
post,28619823474,Inactive,123453395270941,Yes,Yes,Yes
```

File 2 example:

```
123452010988750,123452010988759,promo32,1.11
123453458466100,123453458466199,promo64,2.22
123450000000000,123450000000010,standard128,3.333
```

Result example (currently):

```
prep,28620026059,Active,123452010988759,No,No,No,promo32,1.11
post,28619823474,Active,123453458466109,Yes,No,No,promo64,2.22
```

Result example (nice to have):

```
prep,28620026059,Active,123452010988759,No,No,No,promo32,1.11
post,28619823474,Active,123453458466109,Yes,No,No,promo64,2.22
post,28619823474,Inactive,123453395270941,Yes,Yes,Yes,NA,NA
```

File 1 is sorted after the 4th column
File 2 is sorted after the first column.

File 2 does not have ranges that overlap

Not all the info in file 1 can be found in a range in file 2

Thanks again!

LE:
The script provided by Jonathan seems to have an issue on some records, as follows:

file 2:

```
123456780737000,123456780737012,ONE 32,1.11
123456780016000,123456780025999,ONE 64,2.22
```

file 1:

```
Postpaid,24987326427,Active,123456780737009,Yes,Yes,Yes
Postpaid,54234564719,Active,123456780017674,Yes,Yes,Yes
```

The output is the following:

```
Postpaid,24987326427,Active,123456780737009,Yes,Yes,Yes,ONE 32,1.11
Postpaid,54234564719,Active,123456780017674,Yes,Yes,Yes,ONE 32,1.11
```

and it should be:

```
Postpaid,24987326427,Active,123456780737009,Yes,Yes,Yes,ONE 32,1.11
Postpaid,54234564719,Active,123456780017674,Yes,Yes,Yes,ONE 64,2.22
```

It seems that it returns 0 and writes the info on first record from file2...

Comment: Please provide small example input files and an expected output. Which fields do you want to join on?

Comment: You should read the 6,000 lines from file 2 into a suitable structure, and then process the 9,000,000 lines from file 1 in a single pass.  This should be done with a scripting language: `awk` is a possibility, though I'd probably use Perl to get the job done or Python to practice programming in Python.  The trickiest part is mapping the ranges in file 2 into a structure that can be used.  Probably you need to use a binary search on the ranges, so you store the 6,000 entries in an array sorted by start order, and then use a binary search in that to find the correct info.

Comment: I have provided file examples and the files are sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work reasonably well:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN   { n = 0; OFS = ","; }
         NR==FNR { lo[n] = $1; hi[n] = $2; i1[n] = $3; i2[n] = $4; n++ }
         NR!=FNR { for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                   {
                      if ($4 >= lo[i] && $4 <= hi[i])
                      {
                          print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, i1[i], i2[i];
                          break;
                      }
                   }
                 }' file2 file1
```

Given `file2` containing:

```
1,10,xyz,pqr
11,20,abc,def
21,30,ambidextrous,warthog
```

and `file1` containing:

```
A,123,X2,1,data01_1,data01_2,data01_3
A,123,X2,2,data02_1,data02_2,data02_3
A,123,X2,3,data03_1,data03_2,data03_3
A,123,X2,4,data04_1,data04_2,data04_3
A,123,X2,5,data05_1,data05_2,data05_3
A,123,X2,6,data06_1,data06_2,data06_3
A,123,X2,7,data07_1,data07_2,data07_3
A,123,X2,8,data08_1,data08_2,data08_3
A,123,X2,9,data09_1,data09_2,data09_3
A,123,X2,10,data10_1,data10_2,data10_3
A,123,X2,11,data11_1,data11_2,data11_3
A,123,X2,12,data12_1,data12_2,data12_3
A,123,X2,13,data13_1,data13_2,data13_3
A,123,X2,14,data14_1,data14_2,data14_3
A,123,X2,15,data15_1,data15_2,data15_3
A,123,X2,16,data16_1,data16_2,data16_3
A,123,X2,17,data17_1,data17_2,data17_3
A,123,X2,18,data18_1,data18_2,data18_3
A,123,X2,19,data19_1,data19_2,data19_3
A,223,X2,20,data20_1,data20_2,data20_3
A,223,X2,21,data21_1,data21_2,data21_3
A,223,X2,22,data22_1,data22_2,data22_3
A,223,X2,23,data23_1,data23_2,data23_3
A,223,X2,24,data24_1,data24_2,data24_3
A,223,X2,25,data25_1,data25_2,data25_3
A,223,X2,26,data26_1,data26_2,data26_3
A,223,X2,27,data27_1,data27_2,data27_3
A,223,X2,28,data28_1,data28_2,data28_3
A,223,X2,29,data29_1,data29_2,data29_3
```

the output of the command is:

```
A,123,X2,1,data01_1,data01_2,data01_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,2,data02_1,data02_2,data02_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,3,data03_1,data03_2,data03_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,4,data04_1,data04_2,data04_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,5,data05_1,data05_2,data05_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,6,data06_1,data06_2,data06_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,7,data07_1,data07_2,data07_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,8,data08_1,data08_2,data08_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,9,data09_1,data09_2,data09_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,10,data10_1,data10_2,data10_3,xyz,pqr
A,123,X2,11,data11_1,data11_2,data11_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,12,data12_1,data12_2,data12_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,13,data13_1,data13_2,data13_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,14,data14_1,data14_2,data14_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,15,data15_1,data15_2,data15_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,16,data16_1,data16_2,data16_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,17,data17_1,data17_2,data17_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,18,data18_1,data18_2,data18_3,abc,def
A,123,X2,19,data19_1,data19_2,data19_3,abc,def
A,223,X2,20,data20_1,data20_2,data20_3,abc,def
A,223,X2,21,data21_1,data21_2,data21_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,22,data22_1,data22_2,data22_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,23,data23_1,data23_2,data23_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,24,data24_1,data24_2,data24_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,25,data25_1,data25_2,data25_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,26,data26_1,data26_2,data26_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,27,data27_1,data27_2,data27_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,28,data28_1,data28_2,data28_3,ambidextrous,warthog
A,223,X2,29,data29_1,data29_2,data29_3,ambidextrous,warthog
```

This uses a linear search on the list of ranges; you can write functions in `awk` and a binary search looking for the correct range would perform better on 6,000 entries.  That part, though, is an optimization — exercise for the reader.  Remember that the first rule of optimization is: **don't**.  The second rule of optimization (for experts only) is: don't do it yet.  Demonstrate that it is a problem.  This code shouldn't take all that much longer than the time it takes to copy the 9,000,000 record file (somewhat longer, but not disastrously so).  Note, though, that if the `file1` data is sorted, the tail of the processing will take longer than the start because of the linear search.  If the serial numbers are in a random order, then it will all take about the same time on average.

If your CSV data has commas embedded in the text fields, then  `awk` is no longer suitable; you need a tool with explicit support for CSV format — Perl and Python both have suitable modules.

---

#### Answer to Exercise for the Reader

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN   { n = 0; OFS = ","; }
         NR==FNR { lo[n] = $1; hi[n] = $2; i1[n] = $3; i2[n] = $4; n++ }
         NR!=FNR { i = search($4)
                   print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, i1[i], i2[i];
                 }
         function search(i,    l, h, m)
         {
             l = 0; h = n - 1;
             while (l <= h)
             {
                 m = int((l + h)/2);
                 if (i >= lo[m] && i <= hi[m])
                     return m;
                 else if (i < lo[m])
                     h = m - 1;
                 else
                     l = m + 1;
             }
             return 0;   # Should not get here
         }' file2 file1
```

Not all that hard to write the binary search.  This gives the same result as the original script on the sample data.  It has not been exhaustively tested, but appears to work.

Note that the code does not really handle missing ranges in `file2`; it assumes that the ranges are contiguous but non-overlapping and in sorted order and cover all the values that can appear in the serial column of `file1`.  If those assumptions are not valid, you get erratic behaviour until you fix either the code or the data.

Comment: Nice solution, Jonathan. It would be quite a lot of work to do the binary search, even in Perl. Maybe the OP will tell us how long your elegant solution takes to run...

Comment: Consider my words eaten! :-)

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! I will now try the script and afterwards will let it work over weekend. Will provide the time it takes :)
Also, please note that the files are sorted and no additional commas are in the text fields.

Comment: Jonathan, your solution worked like a charm and finished in ~20 minutes!
Thanks again!

Comment: Dear Jonathan, I found an issue in the script provided by you and I am unable to find the issue. I updated the post with the encountered problem. I would really appreciate if you find the time to have a look as I am on a dead end so far...Thanks!

Comment: Please reread the last paragraph of my answer — and specifically the caveat about sorted order.  Then look at your new sample input (file 2).  If you present file 2 in sorted order — as required by the documentation (notes in the answer) — the code produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix you may use the join command (type 'man join' for more information) which can be configured to work similarly to join operation in databases. That may help you to add the information from File2 to File1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not sure that `join` is really appropriate for this.  It is an interesting and tricky command to use, but the primary defect for this purpose would be that it wouldn't handle range-based joining.